# Reading from Azure Event hub with Kafka driver doesn't seem to get any data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I'm running the following code in an Azure Databricks python notebook:

```
TOPIC = "myeventhub"
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "myeventhubns.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
EH_SASL = "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"Endpoint=sb://myeventhubns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=MyKeyName;SharedAccessKey=myaccesskey;\";"

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("subscribe", TOPIC) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
    .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", "60000") \
    .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "60000") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

df_write = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

This shows no output in the notebook. How could I debug what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.format("console")` then output won't be in the notebook, it will be in the driver & executor logs - it's a difference between Spark and Databricks.

If you want to see the data, just use the `display` function:

```
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is now writing data with quite low latency. Newest datapoint is around 10 seconds old when I do a select in a sql warehouse. The problem still is that foreachBatch is not run, but otherwise it's working.

```
TOPIC = "myeventhub"
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
EH_SASL = "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"Endpoint=sb://myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=mykeyname;SharedAccessKey=mykey;EntityPath=myentitypath;\";"

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("subscribe", TOPIC) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
    .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", "60000") \
    .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "60000") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

n = 100
count = 0

def run_command(batchDF, epoch_id):
    global count
    count += 1
    if count % n == 0:
        spark.sql("OPTIMIZE firstcatalog.bronze.factorydatas3 ZORDER BY (readtimestamp)")

...Omitted code where I transform the data in the value column to strongly typed data...

myTypedDF.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(run_command) \
    .format("delta") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/delta/events/_checkpoints/") \
    .partitionBy("somecolumn") \
    .toTable("myunitycatalog.bronze.mytable")
```

Comment: it's better ask as a new question. But really, you either do `foreachBatch` or `toTable`...  You can move writing to table inside the `foreachBatch` function - just make sure that you do idempotent writes: https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html#idempotent-table-writes-in-foreachbatch

Comment: Where can i find `myentitypath`

Comment: @Aseem In the Azure portal, open an event hub and from the bottom of the overview page select the event hub. Then go to Shared access policies, create one and view the connection string.